# I am using "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" library to make an app which will read the barcodes,but i dont want to show the camera result

Tags: android, eclipse, barcode

I am using "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" library to make an app which will read the barcodes,but i dont want to show the camera result on the screen instead i want to show some other activity which will perform some operations using the digits which barcode will return.

Please explain how to do that.
Regards,
Faizan Tahir

Comment: One up because I need this very soon, too. Lets see what will be answered.

Comment: Did you try to modify `onActivityResult`?

Comment: No,i am quite new in android. And have no idea how to do it! What are your suggestions anyway? Do you know how to split the screen in two parts one for each activity. I want to run the camera in half part and want to perform some operations in the 2nd.